# Parallel semi-online implementation of "top-K array elements"?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, time-complexity

Let A be an array of n integers sitting in main memory, let k << n and suppose I have a single-socket CPU with m cores, each with its own L1 cache and all with a common L2 cache.

I want to obtain the k highest-value elements from the among the n (say, into a preallocated output array B); and - I want this to be fast in practical terms (so both the asymptotic O(*) has to be good and the constants have to be low). And I also have a constraint: No synchronization between the cores and no complex atomic instructions (such as compare-and-exchange test-and-set); integer reads and writes are atomic though.

Two straightforward approaches would be:

1. Each core maintains its own min-heap of at most k elements, updating it with the data it reads from its associated 1/m of the memory (this association can be interleaved for better performance).
2. All cores maintain a single heap in parallel somehow (lock-free heap?)

Approach 1 is more promising if each core's heap fits into its L1; otherwise it might not be worth the trouble (depending on memory bandwidth and insertion frequency I suppose).

Also, I was thinking of starting with some sort of sampling, to have a conservative guess of a cutoff value under which we don't bother inserting into the heap, to avoid excessive insertions.

Is there a radically different approach you would consider? Or a further improvement on my thoughts by an additional trick of some kind?

**Notes:**

- The input is read-only, i.e. any reordering of input data can only happen out-of-place.
- Please ignore other specifics such as what kind of microarchitecture this is exactly, whether there's "hyperthreading" etc. If you feel that's essential, say so in the comments.
- It is preferable (but not necessary) for the additional memory complexity to depend only on k and m rather than on n.

Answer (score 0):

You could base your answer on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect instead of heaps. Since quickselect is linear time, this would save you a factor of log n in asymptotic complexity. You also have the option of using parallel processing to run each stage of quickselect, rather than dividing the data into m parts and running m independent quickselects. (Edits from here)

It is relatively easy to split the data into m parts and process each part separately, and doing this is something that applies to other problems, so it's probably worth doing things this way for consistency, so let's go with that.

Doing this in O(mk) writeable space (in fact 2k for each processor) instead of O(n). Consider just one processor. Divide the data up into chunks of size k. Take the first two chunks and run quickselect to find the top k from those 2k. Append the next chunk of k items to get a chunk of size 2k and repeat to get the top k items of the first 3k data items. Keep going with chunks of k items until you reach the end of that processor's workload. There are n/m items to consider, and we have a total of just under n/(mk) quickselect runs to do, each of which takes us time O(m) so the cost of this is O(n/m) - linear in the data this processor needs to deal with.

Comment: 1. How would you make all cores choose the same pivot value and synchronize phases of the quickselect 2. I would need quite a lot of extra memory (I can't do my work in-place); although that's not a deal breaker I guess.

Comment: It is probably easier to cut up the data into m parts, and that is also a generally applicable strategy that would be useful on other problems. However you could have one core act as leader or you could use random number based randomization with everybody using the same seed. If you have one core as leader you could probably cobble together some sort of master-slave protocol allowing it to exchange messages with the others using only atomic reads and writes and then build synchronization on top of this. I don't see a way to avoid extra memory or in place without losing that factor of log(n).

Comment: OK - I should have remembered there was a way to use quickselect to find the top k using only O(k) space per processor - I have edited my answer to show this, and also to go for the easy option of letting each processor handle its own share of the data - clearly we are both ignoring the final process of combining all the answers.